# Apache root domain SSL virtual host doesnt work?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I have an apache installation at `mydomain.com` with document root at:

```
/var/www/html/
```

There are three folders in document root:

```
myapp1
myapp2
mysite
```

I want the following configuration with subdomains:

```
myapp1.mydomain.com --> /var/www/html/myapp1
myapp2.mydomain.com --> /var/www/html/myapp2
www.mydomain.com --> /var/www/html/mysite
mydomain.com --> /var/www/html/mysite
```

The configuration has to work for plain text HTTP and for HTTPS. I've used virtual hosts to achieve this. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp1
    ServerName myapp1.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp1
    ServerName myapp1.mydomain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Same configuration is for `myapp2` and `www.mydomain.com`. But I have a problem when I try to configure the SSL virtual host for the root domain: `mydomain.com`. This is the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work. Going to `https://mydomain.com` brings me to the default document root (`/var/www/html`) and displays apache default welcome page. It seems that apache doesn't register this virtual host. It's interesting that a virtual host for plain HTTP `mydomain.com` works i.e. going to `http://mydomain.com` brings me to the `/var/www/html/mysite`.

Why can't I have a SSL virtual host for root domain while every other virtual host works just fine?

Answer (score 1):

There's another `VirtualHost` block for port 443 somewhere, either loading before your intended ones or bound to a specific address instead of `*`, which is getting the requests to that location; that's the only way that content would get served.

Beyond that, for the config that you are aiming for, you also need to make sure that you have a `NameVirtualHost *:443` directive alongside the existing `NameVirtualHost *:80`; depends on your config layout, but usually in ports.conf.

Comment: I would imagine the initial VirtualHost configuration in the default file would be what is causing the override.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.

I followed the advice about another VirtualHost that is blocking my own configuration and found it. It was and:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

defined in ssl.conf. The thing is that the file was in conf.d/ (running on Fedora) directory so I didn't notieced it.